# Custom UiTableViewCell from nib without reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I need to load the custom cell with a NIB associated in a table without using "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"

The cells must be loaded new, do not want to reuse the old ..

suppose that the class is called "CustomCell.h and CustomCell.m" and the NIB CustomCell.xib

How can I allocate and initialize the cell does not use them?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomCell *cell = ??

//cell customization

return cell
```

}

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Presume this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551597/without-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-how-to-load-all-array-value-into-uitab - I don't think reuse is your problem. Reusing cells is _faster_, unless you're removing every single subview in the cell.

Answer (score 7):

You can load CustomCell with `loadNibNamed` method of NSBundle as follow.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibFile" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]

//cell customization

return cell
}
```

Why you don't want to reuse the cell ? any specific reason ? It would be more memory consuming as each time it will create a new cell. You can use code as follow to reuse if you need,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(!cell)
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibFile" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]

//cell customization

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomCell *theCell = (MyCellClass*) [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellNibFile" owner:self options:nil] ;
```